# How to delete Hashcodes in HTTP consul

Tags: java, http, apache-nifi, hashcode

we have a NiFi application where we creating the Hash codes to the incoming files, these Hash codes we are storing in HTTP consul[http://xxxxxxx:xxx/]. The reason why creating the HashCodes to avoid duplicate file processing, same file should not come again. The application everything working fine.

Problem Statement:

Day by day hash codes are increasing and utilising more memory in the HTTP consul. I want to delete these Hash codes if older 30 days. Please suggest different approaches how i can delete Hash codes and this program run every alternative day cleanup the data in HTTP consul.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: add created date when you first time hash code log

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use some database for storing the hashcodes, consul is rather for storing configuration data and hascodes are not configuration. If you insist on storing this in consul you can create a standalone service which will delete the hascodes when they are not needed anymore.

Comment: Hi @Krzysztof Cichocki,

Let me know how i can find De-Dupe(Duplicate) hashes in HTTP consul.